# Add data to new column and first row in CSV file

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I have a python function that creates a CSV file using a Postgresql [copy statement](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert). I need to add a new column to this spreadsheet called 'UAL' with an example value in the first row of say 30,000, but without editing the copy statement. This is the current code:

```
copy_sql = 'COPY (
  SELECT
    e.name AS "Employee Name",
    e.title AS "Job Title"
    e.gross AS "Total Pay",
    e.total AS "Total Pay & Benefits",
    e.year AS "Year",
    e.notes AS "Notes",
    j.name AS "Agency",
    e.status AS "Status"

  FROM employee_employee e
  INNER JOIN jurisdiction_jurisdiction j on e.jurisdiction_id = j.id
  WHERE

      e.year = 2011 AND
      j.id = 4479

  ORDER BY "Agency" ASC, "Total Pay & Benefits" DESC
  )'

with open(path, 'w') as csvfile:
    self.cursor.copy_expert(copy_sql, csvfile)
```

What I am trying to do is use something like csv.writer to add content like this:

```
    with open(path, 'w') as csvfile:
        self.cursor.copy_expert(copy_sql, csvfile)
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow('test123')
```

But this is adding the text to the last row. I am also unsure how to add a new header column. Any advice?

Comment: `writer.writerow('test123')` is creating as many columns as there are characters; You need to pass a list.

Comment: Good point. But the content is still in the last row, all the way to the left column.

Comment: adding a header is easy: write the header _before_ the call to copy_expert. But adding a column cannot be done without re-reading the file again and add your info on each row.

Answer (score 0):

adding a header is easy: write the header *before* the call to `copy_expert`.

```
with open(path, 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(["my","super","header"])
    self.cursor.copy_expert(copy_sql, csvfile)
```

But adding a column cannot be done without re-reading the file again and add your info on each row, so the above solution doesn't help much.

If the file isn't too big and fits in memory, you could write the sql output to a "fake" file:

```
import io
fakefile = io.StringIO()
self.cursor.copy_expert(copy_sql, fakefile)
```

now rewind the file and parse it as `csv`, add the extra column when writing it back

```
import csv
fakefile.seek(0)
with open(path, 'w', newline="") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    reader = csv.reader(fakefile)  # works if copy_expert uses "," as separator, else change it
    writer.writerow(["my","super","header","UAL"])
    for row in reader:
       writer.writerow(row+[30000])
```

or instead of the inner loop:

```
    writer.writerows(row+[30000] for row in reader)
```

And if the file is too big, write it in a temp file, and proceed the same way (less performant)